How to get the derivative of the trace of a matrix?
A matrix $W \in \mathbb R^{p \times p}$ is a DAG if and only if
$$h(W)=\operatorname{tr}(e^{W \circ W})-p=0,$$where $\circ$ is the Hadamard product and $e^A$ is the matrix exponential of A. Moreover, $h(W)$ has a simple gradient
$$\nabla h(W) = (e^{W \circ W})^T \circ 2W$$
Question: I don't know how to get this gradient.
My wrong attempt:
To compute the derivative of the trace term $\text{tr}(e^{W \circ W})$, I find this reference is useful: \url{http://paulklein.ca/newsite/teaching/matrix%20calculus.pdf}
$\frac{\partial \text{tr}(f(W))}{\partial W} = \frac{\partial \text{tr}(f(W))}{\partial f(W)} \frac{\partial f(W)}{\partial W}$ , where $f(W)$ is a matrix function of $W$. In this case, $f(W) = e^{W \circ W}$.
By using the equation (9) from the above reference, we can see that $ \frac{\partial \text{tr}(f(W))}{\partial f(W)}  = I$, where $I$ denotes the identity matrix.
We are left to compute $\frac{\partial f(W)}{\partial W}$.
Let $M = W \circ W$. Express $f(W)$ in terms of $M$: $f(W) = e^M$.
Differentiate $f(W)$ with respect to $M$: $\frac{\partial f(W)}{\partial M} = \frac{\partial e^M}{\partial M}$.
Apply the derivative of the matrix exponential function: $\frac{\partial e^M}{\partial M} = e^M$.
Replace $M$ with $W \circ W$ in the expression: $\frac{\partial f(W)}{\partial M} = e^{W \circ W}$.
Finally, we have $\frac{\partial f(W)}{\partial W} = \frac{\partial f(W)}{\partial M} \cdot \frac{\partial (W \circ W)}{\partial W}$.
Compute the derivative of $(W \circ W)$ with respect to $W$. Since the Hadamard product is element-wise, we have $\frac{\partial (W \circ W)}{\partial W} = 2W$.
Multiply $\frac{\partial f(W)}{\partial M}$ with $\frac{\partial (W \circ W)}{\partial W}$: $\frac{\partial f(W)}{\partial W} = e^{W \circ W} \cdot 2W$.

@TobySaunders Yes, obviously there's some mistakes in my method, since I get a wrong result.

If $f$ is analytic, there's a neat trace trick
$$
\phi = \operatorname{tr}(f(X)) \quad\implies\quad
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial X} = f'(X^T) \
$$
Now substitute $,X=W\circ W;$

@greg Is there any reference? Thanks!

@greg I am interested in your idea. Could you give more details and write an answer for me?

Let $g(W)=W\circ W$ and $f(A)=\operatorname{tr}(e^A)-p$. By the tracial property $\operatorname{tr}(XY)=\operatorname{tr}(YX)$, we have
\begin{align*}
&f(A+H)-f(A)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}(e^{A+H})-\operatorname{tr}(e^A)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\left(I+(A+H)+\frac{1}{2!}(A+H)^2+\frac{1}{3!}(A+H)^3+\cdots\right)
-\operatorname{tr}\left(I+A+\frac{1}{2!}A^2+\frac{1}{3!}A^3+\cdots\right)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\left(H+\frac{1}{2!}(AH+HA)+\frac{1}{3!}(A^2H+AHA+HA^2)+\cdots\right)+O\left(\|H\|^2\right)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\left(H+\frac{1}{2!}2AH+\frac{1}{3!}3A^2H+\cdots\right)+O\left(\|H\|^2\right)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}(e^{A}H)+O\left(\|H\|^2\right).\\
\end{align*}
Therefore the differential (Fréchet derivative) of $f$ is the linear map $Df(A):H\mapsto\operatorname{tr}(e^{A}H)$. Since $(W+X)\circ(W+X)-W\circ W=2W\circ X+X\circ X$, we also obtain $Dg(W):X\mapsto 2W\circ X$. So, by the chain rule, $Dh(W)=Df(g(W))Dg(W)$ is the linear functional
$$
Dh(W):X\mapsto
\operatorname{tr}\left(e^{W\circ W}(2W\circ X)\right)
=\operatorname{tr}\left((e^{W\circ W}\circ2W^T)X\right)
=\left\langle e^{(W\circ W)^T}\circ2W,\,X\right\rangle_F
$$
where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_F$ denotes Frobenius inner product. In this sense, the gradient of $h$ at $W$ is $e^{(W\circ W)^T}\circ2W$.

I can understand that $(W+X)\circ(W+X)-W\circ W=2W\circ X+X\circ X$. But how to get $Dg(W)=2W\circ X$?

@Jonathen It’s because $2W\circ X$ is the first-order term in $(W+X)\circ(W+X)-W\circ W$.

I think there's a typo in your answer. The chain rule $Dh(W)=Df(g(W))Dg(W)$. This notation is weird for me. It looks like you are trying to apply $Df(g(W))$ to the result of $Dg(W)$?

@Jonathen Yes, it’s a composition of two linear maps.

Could you tell me why
from $\operatorname{tr}\left(e^{W\circ W}(2W\circ X)\right)$ to $\operatorname{tr}\left((e^{W\circ W}\circ2W^T)X\right)$?

@Jonathen In general, $\operatorname{tr}(U^TV)=\langle U,V\rangle_F$ is the Frobenius inner product between two real matrices $U$ and $V$. If you vectorise the two matrices, it is also equal to the usual inner/dot product $\langle\operatorname{vec}(U),\operatorname{vec}(V)\rangle=\operatorname{vec}(U)\cdot\operatorname{vec}(V)$ between two vectors $\operatorname{vec}(U)$ and $\operatorname{vec}(V)$. ...

... It follows that
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{tr}\left(Z^T(Y\circ X)\right)
&=\operatorname{vec}(Z)\cdot\operatorname{vec}(Y\circ X)\
&=\operatorname{vec}(Z)\cdot\big(\operatorname{vec}(Y)\circ\operatorname{vec}(X)\big)\
&=\big(\operatorname{vec}(Z)\circ\operatorname{vec}(Y)\big)\cdot\operatorname{vec}(X)\
&=\operatorname{vec}(Z\circ Y)\cdot\operatorname{vec}(X)\
&=\operatorname{tr}\left((Z\circ Y)^TX\right).\
\end{align*}
